# Bash: Howto replace only content between brackets if there are only letters

Tags: bash, macos, sed

Let´s say I have this Line:

```
Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [0085]
```

I want to change it to:

```
Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (Taylor Peak) [0085]
```

What is the best way to change the Brackets from [ ] to ( ) **only** when there are letters and whitespaces between them?

[ ] with Numbers should be untouched.

Comment: In OSX/macOS
sed -E 's/\[([A-Za-z ]+)\]/(\1)/g'
is working.

Comment: if you've found one of the below answers to be helpful, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

`sed` works fine here.

```
line="Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [0085]"
echo $line | sed -E 's/\[([A-Za-z ]+)\]/(\1)/g'
```

The `-E` flag turns on extended regex (allows the `(...)` capturing group to work without escaping blackslashes along with `+` to match one or more occurrences).

`[A-Za-z ]` will match only letters and whitespace and thus, won't match brackets with digits (or any other type of content for that matter).

Comment: Wow that was quick. Many Thanks for the Solution and the Explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [0085]' | sed 's/\[\([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\]/\(\1\)/g'
```

The regular expression searches for letters a to z in upper and lower case and spaces between rectangular parantheses.

This range of letters and the space is described with `[a-zA-Z ]\+`. The `\+` means that at least one occurence is needed.

Around that is `\(` and `\)`. This means, store what's been found in `\1`, which is used in the "replace with" part of `s(earch)/look_for_this/replace_with_that/g(lobally)`.

Finally the regex is completed with the outermost `\[` and `\]`. Those brackets need to be escaped so they are not confused with the already mentioned character range.

---

Or you do it like in TrebuchetMS's answer and save yourself some escaping. Leaving this here because of the explanation though. :)

Comment: What a concise explanation!

Comment: Wow that was quick. Many Thanks for the Solution and the Explanation. :)